# Gostaria de transformar "a"+str(1) em a1 sem ser uma strig, para poder associar um valor "a"+str(1)=2 como faço?

Tags: string, python-3.x

```
"a"+str(1)=2
File "<ipython-input-44-929460161ba7>", line 1
    "a"+str(1)=2
                ^
```

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Eu quero criar um série de variaveis
a1 a2 a3 an e depois associar a um valor cada uma

Comment: Desculpe em Python 3.5 sou nova aqui

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de python mas não serio mais simples usar um array?

Comment: Eu quero criar uma série de matrizes que dependem de quantidade de elementos, cada matriz eu gostaria de colocar um nome assim, mas não estou conseguindo fazer, talvez esteja pensando errado, estou começando a programar.

Comment: Ola Catia, eu não consegui entender direito o que você está querendo fazer...  `"a"` é um literal (uma string),  não uma variável. 
Você quis fazer algo como `a1 = 2`? Tente editar a sua pergunta e explicar melhor o que você está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça um list em vez de tentar criar variáveis programaticamente (o que é possível, mas não é uma boa ideia):

```
a =[]
a[1] = 2
```

Acredito ser isso o que você queira fazer.

Comment: Isso mesmo que queria fazer.

Comment: Lembre-se de marcar como resposta correta para ajudar outros que talvez tenham a mesma dúvida.